# Shutdown Mac Objective C

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, shutdown

I need to be able to implement methods of:

- Shutdown
- Restart
- Logoff
- Sleep

On a Mac, I am using XCode but can't seem to figure out the code to perform these actions.

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks

Comment: This link provides C sample code for everything you want to do: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2001/qa1134.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A trivial/lazy way do this is via some simple inline Applescript:

```
NSString *scriptAction = @"restart"; // @"restart"/@"shut down"/@"sleep"/@"log out"
NSString *scriptSource = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tell application \"Finder\" to %@", scriptAction];
NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:scriptSource];
NSDictionary *errDict = nil;
if (![appleScript executeAndReturnError:&errDict]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", errDict); 
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get your code to work but I have included the code I found on the net related to your code. This one works and is tested. http://pastebin.com/eWhfc5eR

Comment: Sorry, I had no compiler at hand, so couldn't test it. Should have been an NSDictionary, not an NSError, of course. My bad. Fixed it.

Comment: `scriptError` is not defined. Also in later versions of Xcode, autorelease is not needed.

Comment: Does not seem to be working on Ventura. What could be the problem?