# Finder Scripting Bridge to Shutdown

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, scripting-bridge

I tried to use Application Scripting Bridge to send my Mac to sleep.
The code look like the following:

```
#import "Finder.h"
 FinderApplication *Finder = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.finder"];
        [Finder sleep];
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas why it doesn't work? No compiling errors or warnings, but it doesn't work…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103962/perform-certain-system-events-mac-os-x/6105338#6105338), I've been using the following code for over 8 years without issues:

MDRestartShutdownLogout.h:

```
#import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
/*
    *    kAERestart        will cause system to restart
    *    kAEShutDown       will cause system to shutdown
    *    kAEReallyLogout   will cause system to logout
    *    kAESleep          will cause system to sleep
 */
extern OSStatus MDSendAppleEventToSystemProcess(AEEventID eventToSend);
```

MDRestartShutdownLogout.m:

```
#import "MDRestartShutdownLogout.h"

OSStatus MDSendAppleEventToSystemProcess(AEEventID eventToSendID) {
    AEAddressDesc targetDesc;
    static const ProcessSerialNumber kPSNOfSystemProcess = {0, kSystemProcess };
    AppleEvent eventReply = {typeNull, NULL};
    AppleEvent eventToSend = {typeNull, NULL};

    OSStatus status = AECreateDesc(typeProcessSerialNumber,
         &kPSNOfSystemProcess, sizeof(kPSNOfSystemProcess), &targetDesc);

    if (status != noErr) return status;

    status = AECreateAppleEvent(kCoreEventClass, eventToSendID,
          &targetDesc, kAutoGenerateReturnID, kAnyTransactionID, &eventToSend);

    AEDisposeDesc(&targetDesc);

    if (status != noErr) return status;

    status = AESendMessage(&eventToSend, &eventReply,
                          kAENormalPriority, kAEDefaultTimeout);

    AEDisposeDesc(&eventToSend);
    if (status != noErr) return status;
    AEDisposeDesc(&eventReply);
    return status;
}
```

Note that the above code is based on the code from [Technical Q&A QA1134](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1134/_index.html), but mine is re-worked to use `AESendMessage()` rather than `AESend()`. `AESend()` is in `HIToolbox.framework`, which is in `Carbon.framework` and is therefore unavailable to 64-bit apps. (`AESendMessage()` is part of the `AE.framework` in `CoreServices`).

Comment: Great. Found that Apple page too, but saw that it uses Carbon…

Comment: It does not work on 10.13. Do you have any suggestions? I get the following error: AppleEvents: received mach msg which wasn't complex type as expected in getMemoryReference.

Answer (score 0):

If Scripting Bridge isn't sufficient to do something non-application specific, like shutting down the Mac, then you have the luxury of moving to other frameworks that Applescript (and by extension Scripting Bridge) doesn't have direct access to. For shutting down the Mac, see Core Services: [Technical Q&A QA1134: Programmatically causing restart, shutdown and/or logout](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1134/_index.html)