# "Order" a shutdown of the mac with Swift

Tags: swift, macos, countdown, shutdown

I'm making a little software to shutdown my computer after some time (with a countdown)

But I can't find how to send a "shutdown" command with my programm.

In my idea when the countdown is over the Mac simply shutdown.

Thanks you for any reply :)

Comment: Related: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1134/_index.html

Comment: That Technical Q&A is ancient (it uses `AESend()` which is in `Carbon.framework`). See my reworked code here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6105338/277952

Comment: thanks for the awnsers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that via AppleScript and Cocoa:

```
import Cocoa
let source = "tell application \"Finder\"\nshut down\nend tell"
let script = NSAppleScript(source: source)
script?.executeAndReturnError(nil)
```

You can also find a solution by using NSTask and a shell script.

These two solutions are only working if the sandbox is disabled.

Comment: Thanks men i will look your code :)