# Objective-C OS X System Commands

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Does anyone know of any useful system commands that can be executed using Objective-C, below is a list of some that would be useful:

- Start Screensaver
- Sleep
- Shut Down
- Empty Trash
- Eject Volume
- Open Application
- Lock
- Restart
- Logout

Essentially, I'd like to initiate one of these commands when the user clicks an NSButton so it would be a method implemented via that means.

Comment: Why don't you put this as 9 differnt questions, a lot of up votes and even acceptance points...also for answer supplier...

Comment: @dbramhall, this link may help you...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505632/shutdown-mac-objective-c

Comment: I thought it would not only be beneficial to the development of my application but also useful for many of users that have a list in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Screen Saver:

```
- (IBAction)screensaver:(id)sender {
    NSString *script=@"tell application \"ScreenSaverEngine\" \
                             \nactivate \
                             \nend tell";
    NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:script];
    [appleScript executeAndReturnError:nil];

}
```

For Empty Trash:

```
- (IBAction)emptyTrash:(id)sender {
    NSString *script=@"tell application \"Finder\" \
                             \nempty the trash \
                             \nend tell";
    NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:script];
    [appleScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
}
```

For Open Application

use this

```
NSString *script=@"tell application \
                   \n\"Name of application\" \
                    \nto activate";
```

for unmounting of a volume, you need to put a lot of applescript. Here are those: make it an string and pass to NSAppleScript as done above:

```
set diskName to "YourDiskNameHere"
tell application "Finder"
 if disk diskName exists then
  eject disk diskName
 else
  tell current application
   set deviceLine to (do shell script "diskutil list | grep \"" & diskName & "\" | awk '{ print $NF }' }'")
   if deviceLine = "" then
    display dialog "The disk \"" & diskName & "\" cannot be found." buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "Error" with icon caution
   end if
   set foundDisks to paragraphs of deviceLine
   repeat with i from 1 to number of items in foundDisks
    set this_item to item i of foundDisks
    if this_item contains "disk" then
     do shell script "diskutil mountDisk /dev/" & this_item
    end if
   end repeat
  end tell
 end if
end tell
```

---

For [restart, shut down, sleep, logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505632/shutdown-mac-objective-c)

```
NSString *scriptAction = @"restart"; // @"restart"/@"shut down"/@"sleep"/@"log out"
NSString *scriptSource = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tell application \"Finder\" to %@", scriptAction];
NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:scriptSource] autorelease];
NSDictionary *errDict = nil;
if (![appleScript executeAndReturnError:&errDict]) {
    NSLog([scriptError description]); 
}
```

Comment: **Applescript should or should not be used is still under discussion.**